# Error with join in scala spark. org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) missing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Joining two dataframes is throwing a rather weird error in Scala Spark. I am trying to join two data sets namely **input** and **metric**

Snippet I am executing->

```
input.as("input").join(broadcast(metric.as("metric"), Seq("seller","seller_seller_tag"), "left_outer"))
```

The join breaks with ->

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) seller_seller_tag#2763 missing from seller#2483, seller_tag#2484, stats_date#2507, learner_id#2508, keyword_click#2493L, visible_impression#2494L, seller_tag_misc#439 in operator +- !Aggregate [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#2763], [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#2763, sum(visible_impression#2494L) AS visible_impression#527L, sum(keyword_click#2493L) AS keyword_click#529L]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: seller_seller_tag. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;
```

I have asserted both the dataframes have the seller_seller_tag column.

The weirdness->

This is the logical plan for metric https://dpaste.com/7NECV5DWX

This is the logical plan for input https://dpaste.com/DYSGLUWCY

And this is the logical plan for the join https://dpaste.com/AGH2BCN2G

In the plan for join, the column #id for seller_seller_tag changes suddenly, for the metric dataframe ->

```
+- !Aggregate [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#2763], [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#2763, sum(visible_impression#2494L) AS visible_impression#527L, sum(keyword_click#2493L) AS keyword_click#529L]
+- Project [seller#2483, seller_tag#2484, stats_date#2507, learner_id#2508, keyword_click#2493L, visible_impression#2494L, seller_tag_misc#439, concat(seller#2483, __, seller_tag_misc#439) AS seller_seller_tag#482]
```

while the same step in the the plan for metric is->

```
+- Aggregate [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#482], [seller#2483, seller_seller_tag#482, sum(visible_impression#2494L) AS visible_impression#527L, sum(keyword_click#2493L) AS keyword_click#529L]
+- Project [seller#2483, seller_tag#2484, stats_date#2507, learner_id#2508, keyword_click#2493L, visible_impression#2494L, seller_tag_misc#439, concat(seller#2483, __, seller_tag_misc#439) AS seller_seller_tag#482]
```

The plan changes ids on join!
Explanation!?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with spark 2.4.0 (and probably lesser, not sure). Even though the SQL appears legitimate, `AnalysisException` will be thrown when your query has multiple joins. This happens because of the `ResolveReferences.dedupRight`
, an internal method spark uses in the process of resolving plans. Thanks to  **mazaneicha** for pointing this out. You can know more about the issue and reproduce it from here https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-32280

The issue has been fixed in the higher versions of spark (2.4.7, 3.0.1, 3.1.0).
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32280?attachmentSortBy=dateTime